# How to delete rows from a table with multiple select in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, delete-row

I want to delete only the rows that the following statement returns, how can I do that?

```
  select usersernum,username,useremail 
    from core.appuser
   where usersernum in (
              select ch.usersernum
                from core.appusersession ch
               where ch.usersernum not in (
                          select usersernum
                            from (
                                       select max(starttime) as maxstarttime
                                            , usersernum
                                         from core.appusersession  vip
                                        where vip.starttime >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
                                     group by usersernum
                                 )
                     )
            group by usersernum
         )
order by useremail
       ;
```

Comment: Can you state the goal of the query above in English?  It looks like this query could be simplified.  Also what platform is your DB2 running on?  (IBM i, LUW, or z/OS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to take a step back and ask yourself, What is the real goal here, in "business terms" or every-day language rather than SQL.

Your query looks like it has a bunch of unnecessary layers.  It appears that what you really want to do is remove any inactive users, meaning those who have not started a session since the beginning of 2011.

```
DELETE  FROM core.appuser 
  WHERE usersernum NOT IN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT usersernum
        FROM core.appusersession  
        WHERE starttime>='2011-01-01 00:00:00'
    );
```

Isn't that much simpler?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```sql
DELETE  FROM core.appuser WHERE usersnum IN (
     select  usersernum 
       from  core.appuser
      where  usersernum in (
             select  ch.usersernum
               from  core.appusersession ch
              where  ch.usersernum not in (
                 select  usersernum from (
                     select  max(starttime) as maxstarttime, usersernum
                       from  core.appusersession  vip where vip.starttime>='2011-01-01 00:00:00' group by usersernum))
          group by  usersernum)
    order by  useremail);
```

Comment: The '*' must not be there. I tried to edit it but SO requires at least 6 modified characters for accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what platform or version of DB2 you are running, but if you are on DB2 9.7 for Linux, UNIX and Windows or later, you can use the super-handy "delete from select":

```
delete from (
  select usersernum,username,useremail 
    from core.appuser
   where usersernum in (
              select ch.usersernum
                from core.appusersession ch
               where ch.usersernum not in (
                          select usersernum
                            from (
                                       select max(starttime) as maxstarttime
                                            , usersernum
                                         from core.appusersession  vip
                                        where vip.starttime >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
                                     group by usersernum
                                 )
                     )
            group by usersernum
         )
    order by useremail
);
```